# Vuejs call method from href tag

Tags: vue.js

I get this error when I try to call a method from a property:

> _vm.url is not a function

when i try to call a function

```html
<a :href="url(item)" class="link">
    {{ item.label }}
</a>
```

```js
method: {
    url: function(item) {
        console.log(item)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is `methods`, not `method`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property is [`methods`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods), not `method`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a @click="logout">Logout</a>
```

then

```
methods: {
logout() {
  console.log("logout");
}}
```